# How to create table of content in Word Document using Apache POI?

Tags: java

We are creating word document using apache POI. I have pasted code snippet below:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph p1 = doc.createParagraph();
p1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
p1.setBorderBottom(Borders.DOUBLE);
p1.setBorderTop(Borders.DOUBLE);
p1.setBorderRight(Borders.DOUBLE);
p1.setBorderLeft(Borders.DOUBLE);
p1.setBorderBetween(Borders.SINGLE);
p1.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.TOP);

XWPFRun r1 = p1.createRun();
r1.setBold(true);
r1.setText("The quick brown fox");
r1.setBold(true);
r1.setFontFamily("Courier");
r1.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.DOT_DOT_DASH);
r1.setTextPosition(100);
```

But our requirement is create table of content with page number.
Please provide me information how to create table of content....

Comment: I need to do something similar too. Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

To create table of contents you can just use:

```
doc.createTOC();
```

Or you can call:

```
doc.enforceUpdateFields();
```

But this will create a popup in word document with: "This document contains fields that may refer to other files. Do you want to update the fields in this document?", which looks a bit dodgy if you are opening a new doc :)

Comment: But I found that the heading content, dotted line and page number have same style(have default font size,color), how can I set different style for the table of content? Thanks in advance!